# How to get more than 25 items in a playlist using youtube_it gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube

I'm trying to use the Youtube_it gem to pull in a list of videos and store the urls, but the built in objects are only giving me 25 items max each time. Does anyone know of a way to use this gem to do this?

The code looks like this:

```
playlist = client.playlist(playlist_id)
playlist.videos
puts playlist.videos.length
```

In the meantime I think I need to a custom search in order to accomplish this. Any other suggestions and/or gems that my be useful are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: i'd write a loop, but there isnt an option for start index or max results

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with youtube_it, but it sounds like the reason you are getting back 25 results is that is the [default maximum results](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos) that can be returned in a result set. Based on the [help page of youtube_it](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/), have you tried setting the parameter max-results...

```
$ client.videos_by(:query => "penguin", :max_results => 50)
```

Please note that the number of max_results, at some point, is limited by the YouTube API itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm pretty sure that you are no longer in this problem, but I found a solution and I just want to share it.

If you have the id of your playlist you can do the follow

```
@xml = open("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/#{playlist_id}?max-results=50&start-index=1")
    @result = YouTubeIt::Parser::VideosFeedParser.new(@xml).parse_videos
```

In this example, I'm just retrieving a maximum of 50 videos, but as you can see, it's pretty easy to adjust.

Now, @result is going to be an array with the video objects, so you can go throug it with:

```
@result.each do |video|
end
```

There is a little bug, for some reason the unique_id attribute it's empty, but you can get it with:

```
str1_markerstring = "/v/"
str2_markerstring = "&"
@result.each do |video|
   unique_id = video.embed_url[/#{str1_markerstring}(.*?)#{str2_markerstring}/m, 1]
end
```

I hope this can help someone else with the same issue as mine.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Uriel's answer, I wrote a helpful method `fetch_all_videos_from_playlist`.

```
def fetch_videos_from_playlist(playlist_id, start_index = 1)
  xml = open("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/#{playlist_id}?max-results=50&start-index=#{start_index}")
  YouTubeIt::Parser::VideosFeedParser.new(xml).parse_videos
end

def fetch_all_videos_from_playlist(playlist_id)
  all_videos = []
  offset = 1
  while (videos = fetch_videos_from_playlist(playlist_id, offset)).length > 0
    all_videos += videos
    offset += videos.length
  end
  all_videos
end
```

It fetches 50 videos at a time, which seems to be the current max YouTube supports. And a playlist can hold at most 200 videos, apparently. So the method will make up to 4 fetches to get all videos.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution on youtube_it issues center on GitHub:

```
playlists_first_page = @client.playlists('sbnation', {'start-index' => 1, 'max-results' => 25})
playlists_second_page = @client.playlists('sbnation', {'start-index' => 26, 'max-results' => 25})
```

Source: https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/issues/111